# If $\frac ab= \frac bc= \frac cd$ then $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ab+cd)^2$ [sic?]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a basic algebra question. I found in class 9 math book and it is little tricky for me.

> If $$\dfrac ab= \dfrac bc= \dfrac cd$$
>   prove that  $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ab+cd)^2$$
>
> **Note (by @Blue).** As observed in comments, the problem is incorrect as stated. It becomes valid if $(ab+cd)^2$ is replaced by $(ac+bd)^2$, but it is not clear if this is the source's intention.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try expanding L.H.S and simplifying things.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is correct ? By plugging some values of $a,b,c,d$ , I don't get L.H.S $ = $ R.H.S

Comment: This is incorrect. Take $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,4,8)$

Comment: Did you mean $(ac+bd)^2$?

Comment: @MatthewDaly : Did you identify the source of this task to be able to confirm that it is printed as in your change? You completely changed the character of this question, possibly eliminating the problem that OP had with it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The OP who hasn't said a word during this entire discussion despite being asked to?  Meh, roll back my edit and engage them if you wish (and can).  I just wanted the rest of us to be able to get on with our day.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Patience, its been one hour on New Years day. As I don't have a crystal ball either, I have no more justification to edit than you do, so I'll leave it as it is. The OP can react to these comments as they like.

Comment: In your comment, you suggest that the question is incorrect as stated, then question the source's intentions.  Can you please cite the specific "class 9 math book" which you are working out of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, the formula is wrong (or was, until I just corrected it).

Let $\alpha$ be the common ratio, so that $a=\alpha^3d,\ b=\alpha^2d,\ c=\alpha d$.  Then

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=((\alpha^3d)^2+(\alpha^2d)^2)((\alpha d)^2+d^2)\\=(\alpha^6d^2+d^2)(\alpha^4d^2+d^2)=\alpha^4(\alpha^2d^2+d^2)(\alpha^2d^2+d^2)\\
=[\alpha^2(\alpha^2d^2+d^2)]^2=[\alpha^4d^2+\alpha^2d^2]^2\\
=[(\alpha^3d)(\alpha d)+(\alpha^2d)d]^2=(ac+bd)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Using complex numbers and their absolute value one can transform
$$
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=|a-ib|^2|c+ id|^2=|(ac+bd)+i(ad-bc)|^2,$$ 
so with $ad=bc$ the right side is pretty fixed.